# Widget development for wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, open-source, mvvm, addition

I am searching for a design pattern, open source platform or what can else use to develop widget for wpf applications. I need to develop a host application that could load predefined or custom widget and this widget could interact with host application or could communicate with other widgets. User could add new widget without quiting the application or unload. Something like web parts that are used in asp.net or SharePoint. I am searching about Add-ins and Extensibility in Net 4.0 but I am not sure is it the true thing.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384200.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sounds like a perfect use case for [MEF](http://mef.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Overview&referringTitle=Home).